# JavaScript: Calling a variable that has been altered within another function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, cookies, alert

I'm trying to create an alert in JavaScript using cookies that both greets the user by name and tells them how many times they've won a specific game on the website. I have the user greeting working fine, but I can't seem to get the counter to work correctly. It involves calling variables that are altered by a previous function, and I think that's where my problem is, but I'm not sure how to fix that. (The variables are called 'cardOnePoints' and 'cardTwoPoints'.) Can anyone help me with that or tell me if there's anything else I'm doing wrong?

```
function getCookieOne(c_name) {
var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
    x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
    x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    if (x == c_name) {
        return unescape(y);
    }
}
}

function setCookieOne(c_name, value, exdays) {
var exdate = new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" +     exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

var winnerCount = getCookieOne('gamesWonCount') || 0;

function calculateWinnerCount() {
if (cardOnePoints + cardTwoPoints === 21) {
    winnerCount = winnerCount + 1;
    setCookieOne("gamesWonCount", winnerCount, 365);
}
}

function checkCookie() {
var username = getCookieOne("username");

if (username != null && username != "") {
    alert("Sup " + username + "!!! Woah man, you've won " + winnerCount + " game(s)!!!");
} else {
    username = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
    if (username != null && username != "") {
        setCookieOne("username", username, 365);
    }
}
}
```

You can see my entire code here: http://jsfiddle.net/hayleyelisa/9padf/2/

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring those variables within the context of a function.  You'll only be able to access them within the scope of that function.  You can declare them outside the scope of both functions and you can access them within both.

Javascript variables can be accessed from within functions that they're declared outside of, but variables declared within a function cannot be accessed outside of those functions

So instead of

```
function dealHand() {
    ...
    var cardOnePoints;
    var cardTwoPoints;
    ...
}

function calculateWinnerCount() {
if (cardOnePoints + cardTwoPoints === 21) {
    ...
}
```

you want

```
var cardOnePoints;
var cardTwoPoints;

function dealHand() {
    ...
}

function calculateWinnerCount() {
if (cardOnePoints + cardTwoPoints === 21) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, I tried that. Whenever I do that and call the variables, they're returned as null because it calls them as they are declared globally instead of how that function alters them. So I need a way to call them after they are altered by the function dealHand().

Comment: if the dealHand function alters them then they will stay altered.  Are you sure that you're running the dealHand function before the calculateWinner Count function?

Comment: Also make sure that you're not recreating the variables within the function, as the function would then reference those inner variables rather than the globals

Comment: Hmmm okay it's working now, but it's reading 'winnerCount + 1' as concatenating two strings instead of adding two integers, so if a user wins 4 times, it shows up as having won 1111 times. Any thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: `parseInt(winnerCount,10) + 1`